# Searches and exports in Google Vault API

Tags: google-api-python-client

Looking at the Google Vault API, in the matters sections.  There are multiple ways to manipulate matters: get, list, update, close, delete and reopen.

There does not seem to (at least not listed) be a way to conduct a search in a matter, or do an export.

I know there are 3rd party tools out there that do this, but its not listed in the API.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: Doesn't look like it. If they offer search and export, they likely index this information themselves.

Answer (score -1):

You can export using the Vault API
https://developers.google.com/vault/guides/exports